# will twitter revoke my app and access keys if i remove my phone number?

Tags: twitter, access-token, twitter-anywhere

I started using Twitter's API to get access to  information from the users tweets and all the available resources, but i needed to verify with a phone number first.
So I have verified my account on twitter with my phone number, so that i could get access token..etc

**My question is:** 
I have tried removing my phone number, and the access tokens and the app were still verified with no issues. My question is will the absesnce a phone number cause an issues for the generated access tokens ? or will it still work with no issues ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because : this is a policy question for Twitter.

Comment: I have removed my phone number after verification of several apps on various accounts and I have experienced no issues.